# Puppet kubernetes module

Tags: kubernetes, puppet

I installed the puppet kubernetes module to manage pods of my kubernetes cluster with https://github.com/garethr/garethr-kubernetes/blob/master/README.md

I am not able to get any pod information back when I run

puppet resource kubernetes_pod

It just returns an empty line.

I am using a minikube k8s cluster to test the puppet module against.

`cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/kubernetes.conf`

`apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /root/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://<ip address>:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /root/.minikube/apiserver.crt
    client-key: /root/.minikube/apiserver.key`

I am able to use curl with the certs to talk to the K8s REST API

`curl --cacert /root/.minikube/ca.crt --cert /root/.minikube/apiserver.crt --key /root/.minikube/apiserver.key https://<minikube ip>:844/api/v1/pods/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [garethr-kubernetes](https://github.com/garethr/garethr-kubernetes/) package hasn't been updated since August 2017, so you probably need a version of the [kubeclient gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/kubeclient) at least that old. It seems kubeclient 3.0 came out quite recently, so you might want to try the latest version from the 2.5 major (currently 2.5.2).

Answer (score 0):

From the requirements, this could be related to  a [credentials issue](https://github.com/garethr/garethr-kubernetes/blob/master/README.md#requirements).
Or the configuration is set to a namespace with nothing in it.

As show [in this issue](https://github.com/garethr/garethr-kubernetes/issues/31), check the following:

> `kubectl get pods` works fine at the command line, and my `~/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/kubernetes.conf` file is generated as suggested:

```
mc0e@xxx:~$ kubectl config view --raw=true
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
server: http://localhost:8080
  name: test-doc
contexts:
- context:
cluster: test-doc
user: ""
  name: test-doc
current-context: test-doc
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Comment: I am using a minikube k8s cluster to test the puppet module against and curl works.